# How to invoke String.Joing on an ObservableCollection's bound property (to a ListView) that is a List<string>

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, observablecollection

I have a simple Observable collection with two public properties, int ID and List Targets.  The code-behind looks like (simplified code to remove unnecessary and not relevant code):

```
public class MyClass
{
   public ObservableCollection<SomeClass> jobs;

   public class SomeClass
   {
      private int id;
      private List<string> targets;

      public int ID
      {
         get { return id; }
         set { id = value; }
      }

      public List<string> Targets
      {
         get { return targets; }
         set { targets = value; }
      }

      public SomeClass(int _id, List<string> _targets)
      {
         id = _id;
         targets = _targets;
      }
   }

   public MyClass()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      jobs = new ObservableCollection<SomeClass>();
      myListView.ItemsSource = jobs; //jobs is populated from a a loader in Window_Loaded
   }
}
```

The ListView and binding in the xaml look like:

```
  <ListView Name="MyListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=jobs, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window},
            Mode=OneWay}" Width="480" Height="155" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,35,10,0" >
     <ListView.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu Name="contextMenuJobRemove">
           <ContextMenu.BitmapEffect>
              <OuterGlowBitmapEffect />
           </ContextMenu.BitmapEffect>
           <MenuItem Header="Remove" Click="contextMenuJobRemove_Click" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Parent}"/>
        </ContextMenu>
     </ListView.ContextMenu>
     <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True" ColumnHeaderToolTip="Broadcast call targets">
           <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ID}"   Header="ID"      Width="50" />
           <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Targets}" Header="Targets" Width="100" />
        </GridView>
     </ListView.View>
  </ListView>
```

So when the ListView displays, the Targets columns rightfully displays "(Collection)".  Ideally I'd like this column to display something like `String.Join(",", Targets.ToArray())`.  How can this be done, and am I doing this in the xaml or code-behind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method would be a [converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) in the binding.

However this will only update once the property is changed (not the collection contents). So it might be better to expose a display string property in your object and fire change notifications for that property whenever the list changes. If the collection does not change in the first place those notifications are obviously not necessary.

Comment: Thanks.  This is definitely the way to do this.

Comment: @kmarks2: A note on class design, if the `Targets` list is not supposed to be changed i would use a readonly-datatype, drop the property setter, and make the field [`readonly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx) as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use a value converter:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(IEnumerable<string>), typeof(string))]
public class MyArrayToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return String.Join (",", ( (IEnumerable<string>)value ).ToArray() );
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException ();
    }
}

<Window
    ...
    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXCSharpNamespace"
    ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <my:MyArrayToStringConverter x:Key="myconverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    ...
    "{Binding ... Converter={StaticResource myconverter}}"
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a simple value converter:

```
public class ListConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                          CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var enumerable = value as IEnumerable;
        if (enumerable == null)
            return string.Empty;
        return String.Join(", ", enumerable.ToArray());
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                              CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h8wc12c) is quite convenient, you know.

Comment: @H.B.: Didn't know it also takes objects :-)

Comment: Even if it did not i would probably opt for `String.Join(", ", values.Select(o => o.ToString))` instead to avoid the repeated string concatenation, who knows how big the list is.